# Raw Input and Reading in Data

Tags: python

What I currently have is:

```
f = open("SampleList.txt", "r")

x = f.readlines()
y = []


for i in range (len(x)):
  y.append(x[i].rstrip('\n').split(','))


for i in range(len(y)):
z = y[i]
print z
```

What it gives back is:

```
['100000', 'Weasely ', 'Bill ', '9', '1 Discipline', '0']
['120001', 'Weasely ', 'Fred ', '10', '1 Discipline', '0']
['120002', 'Weasley ', 'George ', '6', '1 Tardies', '0']
['130003', 'Weasley ', 'Ronald ', '10', 'OK', '0']
['130004', 'Longbottom ', 'Neville ', '5', '1 Absence', '0']
['130005', 'Potter ', 'Harry ', '5', 'OK', '0']
['130006', 'MAlfoy ', 'Draco ', '5', '1 Owes more than $5', '$150.00']
['100118', 'The House Elf ', 'Dobbey ', '7', 'OK', '0']
['100011', 'LaStrange ', 'Belatrix ', '8', '1 Discipline', '0']
['100170', 'Dumbledore ', 'Albus ', '7', '1 Administration', '0']
```

What I need it to do know is it to ask say a student to put in a raw input of their student ID number which is the first item '10000' and so on. 
Then it needs to search and determine if that number is valid and if it finds it print off the students name first and last and if they are eligible which is what the 1 Discipline, 1 Tardies, like OK. 
Any help would be vastly appreciated

Comment: Dobby has no e in his name...

Comment: And while we're on names, it's Bellatrix Lestrange.

Comment: Hint: What does `for z in y: print z[0]` print?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary when reading in the file contents.

The dictionary is keyed to the ID numbers from the data file (the first item in each line after you `split` it), and each entry in the dictionary will contain the remainder of the line as a `list`.

```
def student_info(student):
    d = {}
    with open("SampleList.txt", "r") as f:
        x = f.readlines()

    for i in range (len(x)):
        ln = x[i].rstrip('\n').split(',')
        # Add this ID to the dictionary keys, and add the remainder of the line as the value for that key
        d[ln[0]] = ln[1:] 

    if student in d:
        return(d[student][1] + ' ' + d[student][0] + ' ' + d[student][-2])
    else:
        return 'invalid student id#'

studentID = raw_input('Enter your student ID#:  ')
print student_info(studentID)
```